# How do i get this C code to work?

Tags: c

> My knowledge is limited so bear with me but I am experimenting with creating functions and this is what I got so far but it doesn't. All advice is appreciated! Try to create a function that collects input from the user

```
#include<stdio.h>

int GetIntFromUser(int grades[5]);

int GetIntFromUser(int grades[5])
{
    int counter = 0;
    int incre = 1;

    while(counter < 4)
    {
        printf("Please enter GPA %d: ",incre);
        scanf("%d",&grades[counter]);
        incre++;
        counter++;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int sum = 0;
    int grades[5];
    int counter = 0;

    printf(GetIntFromUser());

    while(counter < 4)
    {
        sum = sum + grades[counter];
        counter++;
    }

    float gpa = (float)sum/counter;
    printf("The average GPA is %.2f\n",gpa);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First: `GetIntFromUser` you are declaring your function twice, also, which errors do you get if any ??

Comment: Why the... why are you passing GetIntFromUser to printf ? `printf(GetIntFromUser());` this is useless as long as you don't return any strings inside `GetIntFromUser()` (which you don't, you use printf aswell)

Comment: There seems to be a lot of issues with this code, you should specify specific problems you have instead of just "This doesn't work, help!!"

Comment: @chevybow It's "unclear what you are asking" as there is NO actual problems defined in this post other than "this doesn't work help" as you said, and even then, an obviously bad code doesn't immediately fits under the "too broad" flag, not as long as there is only one specific question asked by OP. Basically "bad code =/= too broad, bad code = bad code"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always tell us what your actual problem is. What do you expect and what does happen instead. Be as precise as possible. Also please enable warnings in your compiler. For GCC this can be done using -Wall -Wextra . If there are warnings, solve them or at least tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void GetIntFromUser(int grades[5]); //void since you do not return anything

void GetIntFromUser(int grades[5])
{
    int counter = 0;
    int incre = 1;

    while(counter < 4)
    {
        printf("Please enter GPA %d: ",incre);
        scanf("%d",&grades[counter]);
        incre++;
        counter++;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int sum = 0;
    int grades[5];
    int counter = 0;

    GetIntFromUser(grades); // Correct function call

    while(counter < 4)
    {
        sum = sum + grades[counter];
        counter++;
    }

    float gpa = (float)sum/counter;
    printf("The average GPA is %.2f\n",gpa);

    return 0;
}
```

You also have an array of 5 elements but you only use 4.

Comment: thank you that was very helpful!! wasn't grasping the concept the way my instructor was explaining it